# Chapter.Part.Section numbering

Tags: sectioning, numbering

Is it possible to have numbering such that my Chapters can contain Parts which contain Sections?

Currently I have:

```
Chapter
    Section{foo}
    Section{far}
    Part{baz}
        Section{bar}
    Part{Caz}
        Section{Coo}
```

which is being numbered:

```
 3.1 Foo
 3.2 Far
 I Baz
    3.3 Bar
 II Caz
    3.4 Coo
```

I want to have:

```
 3.1 Foo
 3.2 Far
 I Baz
     I.1 Bar
 II Caz
     II.1 Coo
```

As I'm writing this question I'm thinking perhaps it's easiest to disable `chapter` numbering in each `Part`, rather than having the `Parts` as subsections to `Chapter`:

```
Chapter
    Section{foo}
    Section{far}
Part{baz} % Disable chapter numbering...
    Section{bar}
Part{Caz} % Disable chapter numbering...
    Section{Coo}
% Re-enable chapter numbering...
```

But I'm not sure (a) if this is the best solution or (b) how to achieve this.

Comment: What `\documentclass` are you using? `report` or `book`, or perhaps something different altogether?

Comment: ...also, are you using the standard definitions for formatting within the Table of Contents?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is a true mock-up of your requirements, however bizarre:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{section}{part}% Reset section counter with every \part
\newcounter{tempsection}
\newcommand{\sectionbypart}{%
  \setcounter{tempsection}{\value{section}}% Store section counter
  \setcounter{section}{0}% Reset section counter
  \renewcommand{\thesection}{\thepart.\arabic{section}}% Section counter display
}
\newcommand{\sectionbychapter}{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}% Add gap in ToC when reverting to by-\chapter numbering
  \setcounter{section}{\value{tempsection}}% Restore section counter
  \renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter.\arabic{section}}% Section counter display
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{A chapter}\lipsum[1-10]
\section{foo}\lipsum[11-20]
\section{far}\lipsum[21-30]
\sectionbypart% Modify section counter to work on a by-\part basis
\part{baz}\lipsum[31-40]
\section{bar}\lipsum[41-50]
\part{Caz}\lipsum[51-60]
\section{Coo}\lipsum[61-70]
\sectionbychapter% Revert to traditional by-\chapter numbering
\section{More foo}\lipsum[71-80]
\end{document}
```

The macro `\sectionbypart` redefines the way the section counter is displayed (`\thesection`) to coincide with the part numbering. `\sectionbychapter` reverts this process by restoring the `section` counter value, as well as its representation.

Answer (score 6):

I wouldn’t use the level macros for the enumeration, that gets messy. ( `\part` introduces a whole page on its own!)

I rather redefine the enumeration style.

## Roman enumeration at the level of chapter

There's no need to patch `\thesection` (to get “I.1”, “I.2”, …) because `\thechapter` was used before, anyway (“3.1”, “3.2”, …).

#### Provided macros

- `\makeChapterRoman`
  This macro saves the current value of the `chapter` counter in the counter `chapterBackup`, sets the style of `\thechapter` to Roman (I, II, III, …) and let the enumeration start with `1`.
  The old definition of `\thechapter` is saved with `\let` to `\oldThechapter` (it’s easier to undo).
- `\undoChapterRoman`
  This macro undoes all changes, i.e. using the old `chapter` value (from `chapterBackup`) and re-`\let`ting `\thechapter` to its initial definition.

### Code

```
\documentclass{report}
\newcounter{chapterBackup}
\newcommand*{\makeChapterRoman}{%
    \let\oldThechapter\thechapter%
    \setcounter{chapterBackup}{\value{chapter}}%
    \setcounter{chapter}{0}%
    \renewcommand*{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}%
}
\newcommand*{\undoChapterRoman}{%
    \setcounter{chapter}{\value{chapterBackup}}%
    \let\thechapter\oldThechapter%
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter 1}\chapter{Chapter 2}
\chapter{Chapter 3}
\section{Foo}
\section{Far}

\makeChapterRoman

\chapter{Baz}
\section{Bar}
\chapter{Caz}
\section{Coo}

\undoChapterRoman

\chapter{Back to normal}
\section{Normal section}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

## Roman enumeration at the level of section

At the default style a subsubsection doesn’t have a enumeration. Even with (the `secnumdepth` counter being greater than 2) there’s no need to redefine `\thesubsubsection` because it uses `\thesubsection` and not the raw `\arabic…` commands.

#### Provided macros

- `\makeSectionRoman`
- `\undoSectionRoman`

### Code

```
\documentclass{report}
\newcounter{sectionBackup}
\newcommand*{\makeSectionRoman}{%
    \let\oldThesection\thesection%
    \let\oldThesubsection\thesubsection%
    \setcounter{sectionBackup}{\value{section}}%
    \setcounter{section}{0}%
    \renewcommand*{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}%
    \renewcommand*{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}%
}
\newcommand*{\undoSectionRoman}{%
    \setcounter{section}{\value{sectionBackup}}%
    \let\thesection\oldThesection%
    \let\thesubsection\oldThesubsection%
}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter 1}\chapter{Chapter 2}
\chapter{Chapter 3}
\section{Foo}\section{Far}

\makeSectionRoman
\section{Baz}
\subsection{Bar}
\section{Caz}
\subsection{Coo}
\undoSectionRoman

\section{Back to normal}
\subsection{Normal section}
\subsection{Another normal section}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]